# maven project from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have this problem opening a maven project from Eclipse

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.8: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.8 from/to repository-apache-org (https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/): Connection refused: no further information to https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/junit/junit/4.8/junit-4.8.pom

Comment: You can always try mvn -U clean install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Connection refused" could be a proxy server issue if you cannot reach external repositories.

Check your settings.xml for which external repo's you're referring to and can you reach them using your web browser?

To check which settings.xml is being used when you run Maven use the debug switch `-X`

```
> mvn -X
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=C:\Users\brad
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000)
Maven home: c:\tools\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.8.0_20, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\tools\jdk1.8.0_20\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from c:\tools\apache-maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\brad\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\sandbox\.m2\repository
...
```

If that's all ok, try removing the local directory for junit from your local repository. This will either be in your home directory under `.m2` or a directory specified by `<localRepository>` in your settings.xml

Eclipse defines its maven settings under

```
Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations
Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `mvn -U clean install`. The -U option should force check for updated releases.